# HornetQ pooled-connection-factory* to receive messages via a JNDI look up - effects?

Tags: jboss7.x, hornetq, mq

The hornet Q documentation mentions that

> A pooled-connection-factory looked up in JNDI or injected which is
>   referencing an in-vm-connector is suitable to be used by a local
>   client only to send messages to a local server. A
>   pooled-connection-factory used by an MDB which is referencing an
>   in-vm-connector is suitable only to consume messages from a local
>   server.

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Messaging+configuration#Messagingconfiguration-JMSConnectionFactories

Question - Why does the WILDFLY team recommend that pooled-connection factory not be used to receive messages via JNDI? What would be the expected impact if it's used that way?

I have an implementation that uses pooled-connection factory to receive message via a JNDI lookup and I am trying to understand what expected impact we should look for (no issues observed)?